# Update related data with asp.net mvc and entity framework on one-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this model classes:

```
public class Proyecto {
#region Atributos
[DisplayName("Código")]
public string ProyectoID { get; set; }

public string OportunidadID {get;set;}
[DisplayName("Nombre")]
public string Nombre { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Fecha inicio")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime FechaInicio { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime FechaCierreTeorica { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayName("Fecha fin")]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
public DateTime FechaCierreReal { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Estado")]
public Valoracion Estado { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Tendencia")]
public Valoracion Tendencia { get; set; }

public virtual Oportunidad Oportunidad { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<AsientoProyecto> Asientos { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<IngresoProyecto> Ingresos { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<AsignacionProyecto> Asignaciones { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Comentario> Comentarios { get; set; }
#endregion
}
```

and

```
public class IngresoProyecto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ProyectoID { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public double Cantidad { get; set; }
}
```

And this part of a view where I display some of the data:

```
<tr>
<th>Ingresos</th>
@foreach (IngresoProyecto ingreso in Model.Ingresos)
{
    totalIngresos += ingreso.Cantidad;
    if (ingreso.Fecha.Year < DateTime.Now.Year)
    {
        <td>@ingreso.Cantidad €</td>
    }
    else if (ingreso.Fecha.Year == DateTime.Now.Year)
    {
        if (ingreso.Fecha.Month < DateTime.Now.Month)
        {
            <td>@ingreso.Cantidad €</td>
        }
        else
        {
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(p => ingreso.Cantidad)</td>
        }
    }
}
<th>@totalIngresos €</th>
</tr>
```

My model on this view is a "Proyecto", and what I want is to update the value of "Ingreso.Cantidad" of several "Ingresos" (the code of the view is inside a form). With this view code I receive a null list of "Ingresos" on the controller when I save the modified data. How can I pass the data of the modified "Ingresos.Cantidad" to the controller?